# Plane-Line Crossing in 3D Java

Tags: java, 3d, intersection

This post is a reply to: [3D Ray-Quad intersection test in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114796/3d-ray-quad-intersection-test-in-java) 
Because I can't yet comment.

My question is, how did they get: 
A point M belongs to this plane iff it satisfies this equation: n . ( M - S1 ) = 0

How is the (dotProduct(n, (M - S1)) == 0) suppose to tell us that the ray intersects the quad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion Wikipedia answers this question quite well: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry))

> In a manner analogous to the way lines in a two-dimensional space are described using a point-slope form for their equations, planes in a three dimensional space have a natural description using a point in the plane and a vector orthogonal to it (the normal vector) to indicate its "inclination".
>
> Specifically, let r0 be the position vector of some point P0 = (x0,
>   y0, z0), and let n = (a, b, c) be a nonzero vector. The plane
>   determined by the point P0 and the vector n consists of those points
>   P, with position vector r, such that the vector drawn from P0 to P is
>   perpendicular to n. Recalling that two vectors are perpendicular if
>   and only if their dot product is zero, it follows that the desired
>   plane can be described as the set of all points r such that

With other words you have a normal vector of a plane and a vector created by a point of the plane and the point you are checking if it is on the plane. The dot-product tells you something about the angle between the two vector. Therefore if the vector is parallel to the plane, the point has to be on the plane.

Comment: Thanks for the source, I'm starting to see the connection.