# Raytracing - Ray vs. Parallelogram

Tags: c++, raytracing

I am working on a simple raytracer for school and I am trying to implement a ray-parallelogram intersection. My paralleogram is defined in parametric form (p = origin + u * A + v * B). The first step is similiar to ray-plane intersection and I get the possible intersection point P from that. But how do I check if the point is inside the parallelogram? I've taken a look around stackoverflow and found this [3D Ray-Quad intersection test in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114796/3d-ray-quad-intersection-test-in-java) but despite what the title suggests the accepted answer seems to only work for rectangles? I am failing some secret tests ( meaning I don't know why I am failing the test, I only know that I am failing x) ). Maybe I missed some edge case?

Here's my code

```
const auto normal = cross(a_, b_);
const auto num = dot(origin_ - ray.o, normal);
const auto denom = dot(ray.d, normal);
if (-epsilon < denom && denom < epsilon)
{
    return false;
}
const auto t = num / denom;
const auto p = (ray.o + t * ray.d) - origin_;
const auto u = dot(p, a_);
const auto v = dot(p, b_);
return -epsilon < t && t < previous && 0.f < u  && u <= a_.length_squared() && 0.f < v && v <= b_.length_squared();
```

Comment: Since you can represent any geometry with a triangle you'd probably be better off just making your parallelogram out of two triangles and using established ray triangle tests like most things do, unless something about your assignment requires parallelograms specifically. In that case, you can likely do it like ray triangle intersection usually works, calculate `u` and `v` then check if they are both less than 1 as that'd satisfy the equation (in the case of a triangle it's usually if `u` and `v` are `< 1` and if `u + v < 1`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do two ray-triangle intersection tests, but it would be more costly since some computations needs to be done twice.

You can test  for ray-parallelogram intersection using the three vectors `a_`, `b_`, and `ray.d` as a basis of the local space of your parallelogram. The advantage of using `ray.d` as the "normal" component is that when you express `ray.o` in this basis, the test for intersection simplifies to check if the local x and y coordinates are between 0 and 1, and the z coordinate encode the distance.

The whole process is:

1. Build the matrix `B` with columns `a_`, `b_`, and `ray.d`
2. Invert it: `B_inv = inverse(B)`
3. Compute `ray.o` in local space: `ol = B_inv * (ray.o - origin_)`
4. Distance `t` is `-ol.z`
5. Test for intersection:
   `if (t >= 0 && t < previous && ol.x >= 0 && ol.x <= 1 && ol.y >= 0 && ol.y <= 1)`